# Issues with replacing the internal hard drive in a mid 2007 macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive

I have a white 2007 MacBook with a 2.0 GhZ intel Core 2Duo processor with a 80GB Serial ATA @ 5400 rpm. Recently my hard drive crashed so I got a new 500Gb Western Digital AV-25 WD5000BUDT 500GB 5400 RPM 32MB Cache 2.5" SATA 3.0Gb/s Internal AV Hard Drive. I registered the hard drive and tried installing the hard drive into my machine. When I try to partition using the disk utility it gives a " Failed to partition ,I/O read/write error". Interestingly for some reason the disk utility tool says that the hard drive is 3.6TB when it is actually a 500Gb hdd. Has anyone ever faced this kind of problem and if yes what is the solution?

Alternatively should I go for a Hitachi hard drive?

Additional information: When removing my old hard drive I somewhat damaged the hard drive bracket. Do you think that this damaged hard drive bracket is the reason?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're not the first person to have problems with this drive in a Mac - see http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/apple-notebooks/217444-macbook-pro-hard-drive-replacement-wont-format.html

It's possible there is a compatibility issue, as you seem to be doing all the right things (and it is connected properly otherwise you wouldn't see it in Disk Utility at all).

The damaged hard drive bracket would not be the cause of the error above.

Try a non-AV drive (one designed for notebooks rather then surveillance/home theatre use) and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Though I went for the original Hitachi drive that one can get from newegg or from macsales.com http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Hitachi/0A57915/

Comment: Glad I could help you out :)